mongoose.connect not a function type error
I am running a database connection to mongoDB using mongoose(v 8.6.2) in next.js and it keeps throwing an error of .connect not being a function, this is my database.js file
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


let isConnected = false; // track the connection

export const connectToDB = async () => {
  

  if(isConnected) {
    console.log('MongoDB is already connected');
    return;
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      dbName: "share_prompt",
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      strictQuery: true
    })

    isConnected = true;

    console.log('MongoDB connected')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

I've tried checking mongoose documentation to see if there's any new syntax for .connect, but I've gotten nothing

Since you're using Mongoose v8.x, certain connection options (e.g., useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, etc.) may be deprecated or unnecessary. You can try simplifying the connection options: await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {   dbName: "share_prompt" }); 


I am running a database connection to mongoDB using mongoose(v 8.6.2)
in next.js and it keeps throwing an error of .connect not being a
function,

It is happening because to call a Server Action in a Client Component, create a new file and add use server directive at the top of it. All exported functions within the file will be marked as Server Actions that can be reused in both Client and Server Components.
Just do this.
'use server'
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

If you are calling a Server Action in a Client Component then try the above code, it will work.
Check the link for detailed information.
EDIT :-
In basic Node.js projects, you can connect to the database in the entry file index.js and you don't call that again.But in Nextjs, there isn't any entry file. Because all the pages and route handlers are specific to the pages or API routes, you can use the experimental feature called instrumentation.
Enable the instrumentation feature by adding the code below to the next.config.js file.
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        instrumentationHook: true,
    },
}

Create a new file instrumentation.js at the root of project or inside src directory if it exist. And add the code below.
import connect from 'path-to-your-database.js-file'

export async function register() {
    await connectToDB();
}

You just need to export the register function and call the connectToDB() function inside it.
If the connection is successful, you will see the message MongoDB is already connected in the console even before you access any page or api route.
For detailed information you can visit this [link][2] where you will get each & every aspect about how to connect with MongoDB using mongoose.

it's "working" it's not throwing any errors but it's not connecting, more like it's not running the async function

@WattiFavour, Remove this line  strictQuery: true and try again.You can also try out this approach that I shared in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/78689128/21210375 .Try this and let me know your feedback.

@WattiFavour , Also check that if this process.env.MONGODB_URI returns expected url string.

@WattiFavour , I have edited my answer and provided more insights about how you can run the async DB connection function connectToDB(). Check my answer once along with the shared URL and let me know your feedback.

I think problem might be due to trying to connect mongo db from client side. There are some points to keep in mind.
Ensure that the Mongoose connection is only initialized on the server side, not on the client side, since Next.js has both client and server components.
It's important to cache the database connection to prevent re-establishing the connection on every request in a serverless environment.
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let isConnected = false; 

export const connectToDB = async () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('MongoDB is already connected');
    return;
  }
  try {
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
      isConnected = true;
      console.log('Using existing MongoDB connection');
      return;
    }
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      dbName: 'share_prompt',
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      strictQuery: true,
    });
    isConnected = true;
    console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error:', error);
  }
};

